# NodeJS version will not change in terminal

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to do an install but it requires node.js 11 or below. I am using nvm and change to v9.0.0.

node -v shows v9.0.0 but then when I do rush install it says my version is 12.(can't remember exact version)

Why would I get this error even after node -v tells me I'm using v9.0.0?

I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: What kind of installation ? What are you trying to install. Please provide minimal working example.

Comment: I am trying to install my work environment at home. It's essentially an autobuild script and it has it run in docker

Comment: can youn paste your error here

Comment: There's nothing to see besides it saying the version is incorrect.

Comment: Your environment variables are probably different between your terminal and the build system. If you do a `node -v` inside the build system you will probably see the version 12.